# instant update of the displayed variable in Flutter (after changing the variable value)

Tags: flutter, dart

I designed a project for weighing, in the flutter app I display the weight in real time (via sockets). The answer I get through the socket I would like to see instantly in the application. But the problem is that the weight does not change in real time (although in the terminal I see the actual weight coming). Here's how I gain weight through sockets:

```
  getWeight() async {
    Socket socket = await Socket.connect('192.168.0.1', 4005);
    print('connected');


    // send hello
    socket.add(utf8.encode('pass'));
    socket.listen((List<int> event) {
      weightSO = utf8.decode(event);
      print(utf8.decode(event));
    });
    socket.add(utf8.encode('pass'));
    await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 10));
    socket.close();
  }

}
```

My Widget:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(height: 35.0),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: <Widget>[
                FlatButton(
                  disabledColor: Colors.pink,
                  textColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  child: Text('Weight', textScaleFactor: 2),
                  onPressed:
                  getWeight,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30.0, 10.0, 30, 10.0),
                ),
              ],
            ),

            Container(
              child: Text(('$weightSO' ), style: TextStyle(fontSize: 45.0, color: Colors.blueGrey)),
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0.0, 0, 20.0),
            ),
           
          ]),

    );
  }
```

Does anyone know how to make it display in real time in the variable `weightSO`, I will be grateful for help.

Comment: Where is `weightSO` actually declared?

Comment: If your `getWeight()` inside the widget class, you can use `setState(() { weightSO = utf8.decode(event); });`. Otherwise, you can use Provider: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple

Answer (score 1):

In flutter there is something called state managment.
Streams,StreamController also you have many libraries you can use based on stream like GetX,Provider,etc...
When the vairable Change sink to the stream when the stream get updated with new variable use streambuilder in the Ui to inform it with the new value to rebuild the widget .